# PHP String Replace - Remove some html content no

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I don't know Regex at all, tried few things I found here and elswhere on the web but none work.

I have this content:

```
<img src="http://example.com/1.jpg" border="0">
<strong>264</strong><br>
Some text<br>
some text<br>
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Link1</a> | <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Link2</a>
```

I would like to strip it so it displays only this:'

```
<img src="http://thumbs3.com/1.jpg" border="0">
<strong>264</strong>
```

I've tried this but first one removes last strong tag as well and leaves second link, the second one removes everything:

```
$item = preg_replace('/<\/strong>(.*?)<\/a>/', "", $item);

$item = preg_replace('/<br>(.*?).*Link2</a>/', "", $item);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: want to replace example with thumbs in the src?

Comment: you can do it like:- https://eval.in/645795

Answer (score 0):

After messing with it more found a combo that works :-)
Thanks all.
This is what worked:

```
$item = preg_replace('/<br>(.*?).*Link2<\/a>/', '', $item);
```

Comment: you can do it with strpos.check my comment

Comment: Is strpos faster or better?

Comment: can't say in your case(because it's really small string), yes but faster than `preg_replace`